# How to write the message.content to a file? (Problem with encoding)

Tags: python, json, encoding, discord.py

I've just started using discord.py and I would like to log the messages. Unfortunately I run into encoding problems. If I write the messages into an utf-8 file, I get the special characters' unicode instead of the character itself. E.g. if I write `áéőúű` into the chat, my bot logs this into the file like this: `\u00e1\u00e9\u0151\u00fa\u0171`. How could I make it so no matter what special character someone types I log into the file the exact character (so the expected result would be to see the same characters in the file, just like I was copy-pasting it from discord to the file).

Since it's just a very basic, "hello world" type of code, I'll copy here the full code:

```
import json
import discord
import os
from time import gmtime, strftime

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    userName = message.author.name + "#" + message.author.discriminator
    writeMessageToFile(filePath='D:\Projects\Discord\messages.json', userName=userName, message=message.content)


def writeMessageToFile(filePath:str, userName:str, message:str):
    messagesData = {}
    timeStamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
    if os.path.isfile(filePath):
        with open(filePath, "r", encoding='utf_8') as jsonFile:
            messagesData = json.load(jsonFile)

    userMessages = messagesData.get(userName, None)
    if userMessages is None:
        messagesData[userName] = [{'TimeStamp': timeStamp, 'Message': message}]
    else:
        messagesData[userName].append({'TimeStamp': timeStamp, 'Message': message})

    with open(filePath, "w", encoding='utf_8') as jsonFile:
        json.dump(messagesData, jsonFile, indent=2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    client.run(token)
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to change the:

```
with open(filePath, "w", encoding='utf_8') as jsonFile:
    json.dump(messagesData, jsonFile, indent=2)
```

to:

```
with open(filePath, "w", encoding='utf_8') as jsonFile:
    json.dump(messagesData, jsonFile, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

And now the output is correct.